# R change integer to three integers

Tags: r

I have this number

`20101213` which is a representation of this data `2010 Dec 13th` I want to extract the year, month and day numbers from that number. So I should have three variables contain the values.

#### What I have tried:

```
value = 20101213

as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(value), "")[[1]])
```

The result is `[1] 2 0 1 0 1 0 1 0`

but I didn't know how to continue, may you help me please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to get this into a date-time format anyways for future computing, so how about:

```
(x <- strptime(20101213, "%Y%m%d"))
# [1] "2010-12-13 EST"
```

This will enable you to do computations that you wouldn't have been able to with just the year, month number, and day number, such as grabbing the day of the week (0=Sunday, 1=Monday, ...) or day of the year:

```
x$wday
# [1] 1
x$yday
# [1] 346
```

Further, you could easily extract the year, month number, and day of month number:

```
c(x$year+1900, x$mon+1, x$mday)
# [1] 2010   12   13
```

**Edit**: As pointed out by @thelatemail, an alternative that doesn't involve remembering offsets is:

```
as.numeric(c(format(x, "%Y"), format(x, "%m"), format(x, "%d")))
# [1] 2010   12   13
```

Comment: I tried to test your code, it works good. However when I enters non data value like `20101313` I got `NA`. I am going to write that code inside another code, so is there a way to do if (you code == NA) ? please?

Comment: @PaoloRLang What day of the year is 13-13-2010?

Comment: @PaoloRLang I actually consider it a feature that this identifies illegal dates (it saves you from implementing that logic yourself). You can identify if a case is missing if `if(is.na(x))` and then do whatever logic you see as appropriate for missing dates.

Comment: @plafort in my country we consider just 12 months. I don't know any value for 13th month

Comment: @PaoloRLang What would you like to see when an illegal date is entered?

Answer (score 1):

```
year <- as.numeric(substr(as.character(value),start = 1,stop = 4))
month <- as.numeric(substr(as.character(value),start = 5,stop = 6))
day <- as.numeric(substr(as.character(value),start = 7,stop = 8))
```

Comment: use `substring(20101213, c(1, 5, 7), c(4, 6, 8))`. way too much writing there.

Comment: Good point!
Since OP appeared not to know substr() I thought an elaborate approach would be appropriate. And he did ask for three variables :)

Comment: Np. use `assign` for variables. `y <- c("year", "month", "day")` then `for (i in 1:3) assign(y[i], x[i])`. In that example, `x` is the name of the `substring` func above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with string representation you could also just use `mod` function like this:

```
# using mod
year  = floor(value/10000)
month = floor((value %% 10000)/100)
day = value %% 100
```

Which will then extract the relevant parts of the number as expected.